# firebase authentication state

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

i'm working on simple login/out , signup web pages using JS and firebase and all methods are ok but the method

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      // User is signed in.
      console.log(user);
    } else {
      // No user is signed in.
      console.log('not logged in');
    }
  });
```

its state is not changing and always popping 'not logged in message in browser console, so what could be possibly wrong with it.
that's the js code of the page

```
const auth = firebase.auth();

//create new account

const auth_var = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(mail, pass);
auth_var.catch(e=> console.log(e.message));
auth_var.catch(e=> console.log(e.code));

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      // User is signed in.
      addUserData(fname, lname, phone);
      console.log(user);

      window.location.href = ../index.html;
    } 
    else {
      // No user is signed in.
      console.log('not logged in');
    }
  });
```

});

Comment: Is the user successfully getting created? Can you inspect the network log in the browser console? If the request is succeeding, inspect `localStorage`/`indexedDB` to confirm the user is saved locally. What environment are you running this in?

Comment: i ran the same pages on firefox and surprisingly it worked, when i login with a created account the onAuthStateChanged() return the user Json successfully, and the network log records the Json post request.
but for some reason the auth is not saved in the local storage, it's all empty and when i tried to redirect after logging in to my home page, i find out that the user is signed out althought it's still signed in in the login page so is this some session problem ?! i really appreciate your help

i'm working on windows 10
firebase version : firebasejs/4.12.1
do you need any other info ?

Comment: They now use `indexedDB` to persist the user and not `localStorage`.